# how to automatically slide/swipe the cell tableviewcell swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how to automatically slide the cell when we touch button like adding contact? is there any delegate for that?

[image: when we clicked the delete button, cell automatically slide]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement `delegate` method - `commitEditingStyle` and you will be done!!

something like,

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    // below code will delete one row - you can mange another kind of deletion here like delete from database also
    if editingStyle == .Delete
    {
        yourDataArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.yourTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And you can do on button's click,

```
   self.yourTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

to show (-) sign on every cells !

Comment: @aldo You might also be interested in checking out `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` which lets you swipe the cell to reveal a button